# Why my JS function automatically fires without click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Basically i would like to toggle class of 'active'. and I want all JS related codes in my main.js file.
I mean I dont want my #readmore button to has onClick=toggle() inside its attribute. onClick method works fine, toggles my 'active' class. But the problem is without doing it.
When I use code below, it automatically adds 'active' class to .container and doesnt removes when I click on #readmore. By the way, i dont want to use jQuery.

My **CODE**:

```js
var myBtn = document.querySelector("#readmore");

myBtn.addEventListener("click", toggle());

function toggle() {
   document.querySelector(".container").classList.toggle('active');
};
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
   <h2>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nesciunt, modi! Ipsum ab non voluptas facilis maxime architecto nulla consectetur recusandae.
   </h2>
   <img src="img/img4.jpg" alt="" width="600px">
   <a href="#" id="readmore">Read More</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`toggle` is executed when attaching the event listener:

```
myBtn.addEventListener("click",toggle());
//                                   ^^
```

We want to pass the function reference:

```
myBtn.addEventListener("click", toggle);
```

Comment: Oh that works!!! thank you so much. But i didnt really understand the problem, can you explain it ?

Comment: you are quicker :) wanted to post it as well:)

Comment: @wasilikoslow, he just replaced `toggle()` with `toggle` in the eventListener, because the first is not known by the code

Comment: @wasilikoslow Since the second parameter expects a function reference, you need to provide one. With your problematic code, you're immediately calling the function and passing its result

Comment: Yes, I understood the problem now... Thank you all :)

Answer (score 2):

In this case where you are writing
`myBtn.addEventListener("click",toggle());` you are calling the function at the same time but you should add a reference to the function, calling the function will done via the addEventListener.

so change your function to something like this -
`myBtn.addEventListener("click", toggle);`

Answer (score 1):

Since the second parameter expects a function reference, you need to provide one. With your problematic code, you're immediately calling the function and passing its result

We need to do something like this:

```
myBtn.addEventListener("click", toggle);
```

You can check out the Docs: [MDN addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
Now, listener will listen for your click event and will invoke the function for you.